# Input value is changed after moving to another tab react js hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have Tabs Component. Inside that I am using Tab component having input fields. When I move over to another tab, input field values are changed.
I have attatched Screenshots below..[Tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/622iD.png)

In that I put 'xxx' for name input field.
[Tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gU9PM.png)
And then I have moved to second tab. Now username inputfield shows 'xxx' which first tab's name input field value.

My code is:

```
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [GSTIN, setGSTIN] = useState('');
const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
const [city, setCity] = useState('');
const [postalCode, setPostalCode] = useState('');
const [country, setCountry] = useState('');
const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
const [userName, setUserName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');
 <Tabs>
      <Tab label={'Company Details'} tabName={'CompanyDetails'}>
        <div className="form">
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name">Name</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="name"
              placeholder="Enter name"
              value={name}
              onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="gstin">GSTIN</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="gstin"
              placeholder="Enter GSTIN"
              value={GSTIN}
              onChange={(e) => setGSTIN(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="address">Address</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="address"
              placeholder="Enter Address"
              value={address}
              onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="city">City</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="city"
              placeholder="Enter City"
              value={city}
              onChange={(e) => setCity(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="postalCode">Postal Code</label>
            <input
              type="number"
              id="postalCode"
              placeholder="Enter Postal Code"
              value={postalCode}
              onChange={(e) => setPostalCode(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="country"
              placeholder="Enter Country"
              value={country}
              onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="phone">Phone</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              id="phone"
              placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
              value={phone}
              onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
              required
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Tab>
      <Tab label={'Admin Details'} tabName={'AdminDetails'}>
        <div className="form">
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="userName">User Name</label>
            <input
              type="userName"
              id="userName"
              placeholder="Enter User Name"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="email">Email Address</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              id="email"
              placeholder="Enter email"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="passowrd">Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="password"
              placeholder="Enter password"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
            <input
              type="password"
              id="confirmPassword"
              placeholder="Enter confirm password"
              required
              onChange={(e) => setConfirmPassword(e.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </Tab>
  </Tabs>
```

Please Help me...
After Update:
[Tab1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hK8TB.png)
[Tab2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7UqV.png)

Comment: You have not passed a `value` prop to your `input`s on the second tab, have you tried doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change type of input to "text" and add a value prop.

```
    <label htmlFor="userName">User Name</label>
    <input
       type="userName"
       id="userName"
       value={userName}
       placeholder="Enter User Name"
       required
       onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
      />
```

Comment: sorry. its by mistake. I changed that. But still showing like that. I have uploaded those images also.

Comment: Could you also show your imports. It would help us in understanding what dependencies you are using. Especially for Tabs.
Is it material-ui ?

Comment: I added value props and then it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input
    type="text"
    id="userName"
    value={userName}
    placeholder="Enter User Name"
    required
    onChange={(e) => setUserName(e.target.value)}
/>
```

You are not providing value to userName field also input type should be text. Try It may work.